# Edge-Side-Includes: How do esi:inline tags work

Tags: http, proxy, edge-side-includes

I have been looking at the ESI (Edge-Side-Includes) specs, but I cannot quite figure out how esi:inline elements work. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: If you insist on creating a new tag for Edge Side Includes, please give it a name *other* than "esi", which has other definitions.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Which definitions, BTW?

Comment: The vast majority of "esi"s here on SO refer to a specific x86 register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out. You send a response with an <esi:include> and in the reply to *that* one you include <esi:inline>-marked fragments for later re-use.

That is a pretty slick way to allow retrieval of many small pieces in one large request.

Comment: Hi, can you provide an example and give more details? I know it's been a while, but there seems to be a popular implementation floating around lately that could be faulty, but it's hard to gather a proper working example on esi:inline so far. Having a working example could really help your answer stand out too.